# File reading using main thread and process data using multithreading and ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement to read bulk data file and process the data (like data validation, tracking validation failures and insert into data base etc..) using multithreading.  I wanted to use main thread to reading data from file and process the data using an `ExecutorService`.

1. Is this the correact approach? if yes, how can I do this?
2. Also, I need to tract every record output once validation and insetion done against to database.  How can I do track output of every record?  Can put it one common variable and increasing the count of failure record data?
3. Also I need to track how many records are failed sequentially?

Thanks.

Comment: Your bottleneck is likely to be the database so I would batch the data first as this is more likely to improve performance (and be relatively simple) For multi-threading examples, I would do a quick search on google. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to split the file into virtual segment and allow your executors to pick and process these segments. Reading the file in the main thread would end up creating bottleneck. Allow each thread to read its segment separately and parallelly. Refer to the following post [How to implement Concurrent read to a file mapped to memory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579808/how-to-implement-concurrent-read-to-a-file-mapped-to-memory-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, but you will have an improvement if processing takes significant time (comparing to reading file), processing of pieces are independent and you have multiple cores.
Read your data to any container (if it fits in RAM) and use any ExecService tutorials like this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct IMO, i would do something like:

```
while ((line = filereader.readLine()) != null) {
    Mycallable mycallable = new Mycallable(line);
    executor.submit(mycallable);
            }
```